# Create a nested table that is three columns long with only html

Tags: html, html-table

This is my problem:

```
<table border= '1' width= '100%' >
 <tr>
   <td> Apple </td>
   <td> Banana </td>
   <td> Strawberry </td>
 </tr>

 <tr> 
   <td> <table border='1' width= '100%'> </td>
   <td> Healthy </td>
   <td> Fruits </td>
   <td> Banana </td>
   </table>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

[image: Table]

The second row is only one column wide but I want it to be three columns wide. And from what I tested colspan doesnt work on the nested table.
Is it even possible to do what I want?

Comment: Your html structure is invalid. Nested table needs `<tr>`  and the cell it is in is closed incorrectly. After you fix that colspans are the solution to balance everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not totally clear what the layout needs to be but once you fix the html structure so cell holding nested table is closed properly, and it's cells have `<tr>` and add some colspans the following should get you close to what you want.

Note that nesting tables is not used a lot any more. It is very old school

```html
<table border='1' width='100%'>
  <tr>
    <td> Apple </td>
    <td> Banana </td>
    <td> Strawberry </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'>
      <table border='1' width='100%'>
        <tr>
          <td> Healthy </td>
          <td> Fruits </td>
          <td> Banana </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>Last Cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```